# Taking code and design from other Websites. Ripoff or Standard?

Tags: language-agnostic

While designing my site I am constantly faced with the issue of whether its ok to TAKE ideas and designs from other sites. In some cases there is no distinction in certain aspects. Is there anything ethically wrong with this? Is this expected in the design programming community?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Depends on how much you 'steal'.**

*Code*

If you're ripping off the whole design, then its a bit dodgy. If you like (for example) the Stack Overflow concept of voting up stuff, then steal the concept and use it in a different manner. If you want to know how say the orange highlighting of the up-voted items works, then look at the code. But don't do both and steal both the concept and the design, you'll just create a clone.

Due to the way different web browsers treat CSS and the like, there are often only a very few limited ways to do a particular thing (3-column layouts, etc.). It seems fair enough to blatantly copy in these cases where there is a common way of doing things. Where its something unique, and there's many ways of doing it, it seems a bit more off to blatantly copy.

*Graphics*

Ripping off graphics - not so okay. Images have been around a lot longer than code so copyright law, etc. probably suits them better. If nothing else you have to contend with possible watermarks or other metadata to identify the original source. It's very easy to check for image stealing, less so for code within a larger block.

I'm a coder, not a designer so what I tend to do is borrow graphics that I like just while mocking up my web-app for internal use. Does that seem fair? I'll change them for newly-designed or paid-for ones before going live. At least that's the idea, though it could be far too easy to forget and use them by accident.

That's the way it works in the newspaper world (well it used to, not sure now with the advent of this there Internet thang): You download as many graphics as you can bother waiting to come over your 57.6k modem; you only pay for the ones you actually publish.

Comment: yeah, in general just don't look too close

Answer (score 8):

Oh, this is a hard question.
On the one hand stealing is wrong, on the other hand you are obliged to save you employer money by solving a task quickly.

My only advice is: 
*If it feels wrong in your gut, you probably stole too much.*

Comment: Lol this is the best comment ever!

Answer (score 6):

I think most designers and developers draw a distinction between 'creative inspiration' derived from someone else's work and blatant plagiarism. 
I wouldn't think twice about peeking under the hood to see how someone had done a particularly nifty javascript effect, or implemented a tricky piece of css elegantly, but I'd find it distasteful to blatantly cut and paste that same code for use in my own development.

I'm not learning anything by just grabbing and reusing - although I think it's fairly standard to have the same code to hand as a rough scaffold from which to explore my own way of implementation. I think that's the way a lot of people work.

Comment: So you're one of those people who got on a tricycle and just moved on, did they ever catch up with you?

For what it's worth, if they really do not want people looking at their code they will tell you somewhere - and there is no reason to work such sites surreptitiously with all the sample code available. ( that's for the others - Steerpike will grasp this )

Answer (score 4):

I am a web developer, not a designer. As such, I have a sense of taste, but not the ability to come up with something wholly on my own. As a matter of ethics, everything commercial or with the expectation of serious traffic that I do, I will hire a designer. They need to eat too, and there is something wrong with making money off of others work and not compensating them for it.

If it is small, personal, or an internal throwaway type thing, I will rip off things like color scheme and/or layout. Technically you could say this is stealing, but I think of it more as "imitation being the sincerest form of flattery" thing. I don't feel that bad about it since there isn't really any money to be made in it.

Answer (score 3):

I think its ok to steal ideas, but not to steal code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how a lot of design is accomplished. Except it's obscured by lots of lifts, not a single wholesale lift.

Answer (score 1):

Stealing resources (graphics, code) is not really OK if they're not specifically marked as free/open/creative-commons/etc.  Stealing design and layout is a bit sketchy if you're just xeroxing the same layout using your own code -- using someone else's design as a starting point is one thing, but don't just recreate their design verbatim.  Stealing snippets of code for specific bits of functionality is fine (IMHO) since even if you grabbed a reference manual to learn it from scratch you'd end up with the same thing. (Think: javascript for changing an button image on mouse-hover)

Having said all that, imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.  Don't steal resources, but using other sites as "influence" should be OK.  Or, if in doubt, ask the owner of the site you intend to use as reference/influence.

Answer (score 1):

It's almost like everyone answering this question forgot what it was like to work with web pages between 1995 and 2002 or so. Stealing was a way of life for tons of designers during that period.  The key was, and still is, to take only what you need, and to make sure that you understand it well enough to make it from scratch the next time.  Who knows, you might improve something in the process.

Comment: Assuming what you say is true, that still doesn't make it right, ethical, moral, or legal.  I'm sure that some web developers continue to steal others' code, etc, to this day.  But that doesn't make it right.

Answer (score 1):

There's an old saying I was once told:  **Good designers create.  *Great* designers steal.**

That said however, you should never blatantly rip off code if you can avoid it.  Look at it, understand it, rewrite it (or improve it, if possible; even if it's only something like using what you find are better variable names) but never just copy and paste.  Same goes for layouts; take the layout and modify it to suit your needs - it might end up looking similar (look at all of the Basecamp-style clones out there as far as UI goes) and that's no big deal at all; plenty of sites look similar.  The key is to go into the situation looking for **inspiration** and not some code to yoink.  If you can use the code as-is or with little modification then you really have no problems, but it shouldn't be your intention to find someone else's code and rip it off.

Comment: The quote is, "Good artists copy.  Great artists steal." Picasso said it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sliding scale. Borrowing just an idea is one thing, if you're incorporating it into the rest of your existing design, not just wholesale copying an idea. Snagging a idea for a design element is fine, copying a whole design exactly is not. As you borrow more and more of a design, it gets into the not acceptable category. Copying directly is also another factor. If you see something you like and reimplement it for yourself, that is typically fine. But doing a direct copy of code, images, or css not so much.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, ideas are fine to take and implement. If people couldn't take existing ideas and expand them or re-implement them, we'd never have gotten out of the dark ages.

If you feel the need to steal code because you can't code HTML/CSS well or don't have an eye for design, steal from a place  that explicitly permits you to use their design/code, like [OSWD](http://www.oswd.org/). In general, stealing HTML is fine, but ripping off CSS wholesale is a no-no. Just because you can easily view the CSS source doesn't mean that it's ok to just copy and paste it.

Don't steal graphics, period. Especially things like photos and logos and icons. If you need that sort of thing, purchase stock photography or take your own photos.

When in doubt, ask the owner of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing code or designs is immoral and in some cases illegal.

Taking inspiration or copying functionality is less of a problem.  For example, at some point in time someone realized that putting a "Forgot Password?" link next to all login forms is a good idea, now everyone does it.  It's not theft it's just replicating a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a web developer, but I might have some insight that will help as well.  My team has created several applications that have served as the starting point for other applications delivered to various customers.

The successful derivatives were those in which the developers took the time to learn the architecture and why things were the way they were.  They then took the more crusty parts and rewrote them and in general expanded and improved the architecture.

Invariably, when a team simply took the existing project and tried to 'brand it' or copy it for a customer without actually figuring out the systems, they either created poor implementations of the extensions or had the project fail outright.

I realize this is a bit off the main topic of the ethical issues address by others here just fine, but my bottom line is that pure theft usually costs you more time than it saves.