# why is this adding padding

Tags: html, css

https://digitalitem.trade/shop/product/pc/windows-10/sea-of-thieves/
The table at the bottom is adding some padding; making text out of line... I don't know why?

```html
<div class="celwidget aplus-module module-4">
  <div class="a-expander-collapsed-height a-row a-expander-container a-expander-partial-collapse-container" aria-live="polite" data-a-expander-name="aplus-module-expander" data-a-expander-collapsed-height="700">
    <div class="a-expander-content a-expander-partial-collapse-content" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="aplus-module-wrapper">
        <div class="apm-spacing">
          <div class="apm-floatleft">
            <h3 class="a-spacing-small a-color-secondary">Sea of Thieves offers something for everyone, no matter how they like to play:</h3>
            <div class="a-spacing-extra-large">
              <div class="apm-spacing">
                <table class="apm-fixed-width a-spacing-mini apm-fourthcol-table">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="apm-center">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">

                          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UMdg1zv.png" alt="" width="220" />

                        </div>
                      </th>
                      <th class="apm-center">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">

                          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o6iR7pN.png" alt="" width="220" />

                        </div>
                      </th>
                      <th class="apm-center">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">

                          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KOmLejc.png" alt="" width="220" />

                        </div>
                      </th>
                      <th class="apm-center">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">

                          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fJh5o2J.png" alt="" width="220" />

                        </div>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="220" class="apm-top">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">
                          <h4 class="a-spacing-mini">A world of exploration</h4>
                          <p class="a-size-small">set sail upon a vast, open ocean, venturing into new regions and discovering the secrets of unspoiled islands and sunken ships. Hunt for treasure by following maps and untangling riddles, and learn to expect the unexpected...</p>
                        </div>
                      </td>

                      <td width="220" class="apm-top">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">
                          <h4 class="a-spacing-mini">A world of excitement</h4>
                          <p class="a-size-small">engage in ship-to-ship crew battles with cannon, pistol and cutlass, pursuing rival ships through raging storms. Sail in pursuit of deadly bounties or ferry cargo through hostile waters. Clash with the skeletal remains of cursed
                            former pirates and beware undersea menaces that lurk beneath the waves!</p>
                        </div>
                      </td>

                      <td width="220" class="apm-top">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">
                          <h4 class="a-spacing-mini">A world we sail together</h4>
                          <p class="a-size-small">whether you’re playing alongside friends, matchmaking to find a crew or setting out as a ‘lone wolf’ pirate, you’ll have hilarious, memorable encounters in a world where every sail on the horizon is a crew of real players.</p>
                        </div>
                      </td>

                      <td width="220" class="apm-top">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">
                          <h4 class="a-spacing-mini">A world of achievement</h4>
                          <p class="a-size-small">on your quest to become a pirate legend you’ll amass loot, build a reputation and customize your ship (and yourself) with your hard-earned rewards.</p>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is from [https://www.amazon.com/Sea-Thieves-Xbox-One/dp/B00ZPT59YS/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ZPT59YS)
Just pasted it into wordpress using visual imput
I cropped the original images to remove blank vertical space that amazon uses; the issue existed prior to cropping the images.

Comment: don't copy and paste other people's code into your site and expect it to work, css is applied from your site, not theirs..

Comment: `td { vertical-align: top }`. Table cells use `vertical-align: middle` by default.

Comment: Curious minds wonder if you sought permission to copy this copyrighted material, was the permission complex to obtain?  That first link is dead/unreachable

Comment: What copywritten materials are there; the screenshots used in the table are assets provided by Microsoft [the publisher] as marketing material for product pages. I am sure Microsoft doesn't care; and enjoy their 200 sea of thieves sold. All of the text and assets are from the microsoft store ; amazon only has a different layout. that I preferred

Answer (score 1):

Because some texts are longer than others, and the `<td>` and `<th>` in a `<table>` use `vertical-align:middle;` as default property, the text is centered vertically in the `<td>`. This **DOESN'T** meen "it adds a padding".

you can fix it by adding this to your css:

```
td, th {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

or:

```
tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

see here for further info: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Because of already existing CSS classes in your HTML structure you could use them as well. `.apm-top{vertical-align: top;}` & `.apm-middle{vertical-align: middle;}`

Snippet:

```html
<style>
.apm-center{
vertical-align:middle;
}

.apm-top{
vertical-align:top;
}
</style>

<div class="celwidget aplus-module module-4">
  <div class="a-expander-collapsed-height a-row a-expander-container a-expander-partial-collapse-container" aria-live="polite" data-a-expander-name="aplus-module-expander" data-a-expander-collapsed-height="700">
    <div class="a-expander-content a-expander-partial-collapse-content" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="aplus-module-wrapper">
        <div class="apm-spacing">
          <div class="apm-floatleft">
            <h3 class="a-spacing-small a-color-secondary">Sea of Thieves offers something for everyone, no matter how they like to play:</h3>
            <div class="a-spacing-extra-large">
              <div class="apm-spacing">
                <table class="apm-fixed-width a-spacing-mini apm-fourthcol-table">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="apm-center">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">

                          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/UMdg1zv.png" alt="" width="220" />

                        </div>
                      </th>
                      <th class="apm-center">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">

                          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o6iR7pN.png" alt="" width="220" />

                        </div>
                      </th>
                      <th class="apm-center">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">

                          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/KOmLejc.png" alt="" width="220" />

                        </div>
                      </th>
                      <th class="apm-center">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">

                          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/fJh5o2J.png" alt="" width="220" />

                        </div>
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="220" class="apm-top">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">
                          <h4 class="a-spacing-mini">A world of exploration</h4>
                          <p class="a-size-small">set sail upon a vast, open ocean, venturing into new regions and discovering the secrets of unspoiled islands and sunken ships. Hunt for treasure by following maps and untangling riddles, and learn to expect the unexpected...</p>
                        </div>
                      </td>

                      <td width="220" class="apm-top">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">
                          <h4 class="a-spacing-mini">A world of excitement</h4>
                          <p class="a-size-small">engage in ship-to-ship crew battles with cannon, pistol and cutlass, pursuing rival ships through raging storms. Sail in pursuit of deadly bounties or ferry cargo through hostile waters. Clash with the skeletal remains of cursed
                            former pirates and beware undersea menaces that lurk beneath the waves!</p>
                        </div>
                      </td>

                      <td width="220" class="apm-top">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">
                          <h4 class="a-spacing-mini">A world we sail together</h4>
                          <p class="a-size-small">whether you’re playing alongside friends, matchmaking to find a crew or setting out as a ‘lone wolf’ pirate, you’ll have hilarious, memorable encounters in a world where every sail on the horizon is a crew of real players.</p>
                        </div>
                      </td>

                      <td width="220" class="apm-top">
                        <div class="apm-fourthcol">
                          <h4 class="a-spacing-mini">A world of achievement</h4>
                          <p class="a-size-small">on your quest to become a pirate legend you’ll amass loot, build a reputation and customize your ship (and yourself) with your hard-earned rewards.</p>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: btw. look at this post about taking code from other websites: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/530280/taking-code-and-design-from-other-websites-ripoff-or-standard?rq=1

Comment: My comment is missing though I remember replying to this... This didn't work... neither by references the .apm nor the table divs. Neither by editing my custom css nor by in-lining it with the html

Comment: I added a snipped which does the exact thing you requested. see the <style> - tag. What is wrong with the result? @ChaythonMeredith please mark it as solution when it helped

Answer (score -1):

adding the vertical-alingn:top inline with an html style worked

```
<td style="vertical-align:Top">
```